# Can .NET automatically support localization for a parent culture?

Tags: .net, localization, satellite-assembly

I have a .NET application that has been translated for the **pt-BR** locale, resulting in a satellite assembly:

```
pt-BR/MyApp.resources.dll
```

I do *not* have a translation for the **pt-PT** locale.  I expected the pt-BR assembly to be used when the pt-PT culture is active due to their sharing a parent culture, but it isn't.

Can .NET somehow automatically use the pt-BR assembly under pt-PT cultures, or do I need to explicitly put my pt-BR translations in a **pt** assembly until I get more pt translations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally the path for a specific localization would be AppBase/pt-Br/xx.dll but you could also put the file in the nutral culture where it looks if it cannot find a specific one. in this case appBase/pt/xxx.dll

Comment: Copying the assembly to a `pt/` directory feels a little kludgey, heh.  If this is the solution I guess the "right" way to do this would be to just move my *pt-BR* resources to *pt* resources.

Answer (score 0):

Yes .NET supports automatic fallback for resources: http://en.csharp-online.net/Localization_Like_the_Pros%E2%80%94Automatic_Fallback_for_Resources

Comment: That link seems to suggest that I need a **pt** assembly as well.  I'm wondering if my **pt-BR** assembly can be made to work for **pt-PT** cultures.